# Delete a record in sink table with KSQLDB

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I had successfully created Debezium Source Connector for Oracle and pulled some **data** to Kafka topics.

After that I create a stream on existing topic that was generated by debezium connector.

```
CREATE STREAM "MySourceTable" WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='server1.DEBEZIUM.MySourceTable', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
--Stream was created successfully.
```

After that I am trying to create a new stream with some data extracted:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "CustomTable1" WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='server2.DEBEZIUM.CustomTable1', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', PARTITIONS=1, KEY_FORMAT='AVRO') AS
SELECT after->customTableId   AS "key_id",
       AS_VALUE(after->customTableId) AS "id",
       after->customTableHref AS "href",
       after->customTableName AS "name",
       after->customTableType AS "type",
       after->id              AS "mySourceTableId"
FROM "MySourceTable"
WHERE (after->customTableId IS NOT NULL) EMIT CHANGES;

--Stream was created successfully.
```

Then I delete a value in column `customTableId` from `MySourceTable` table and it becomes `null` in my source db. I can capture changes from other columns like `customTableHref` and `customTableName` and the result in sink db. But I still have the records with `null` `id` from source db that are not `null` in sink db and they are still exist in my sink table (`id` is primary key in my sink table). How can solve this problem ?

Comment: How are you configuring your sink connector? Does this article help? https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/#_deleting_records_in_the_target_database_with_kafka_connect_jdbc_sink_connector

Comment: Hi @robin-moffatt! I followed your tutorials and connector works great. I tested with the same db structure (Oracle->Postgres). Now I have different structure of source db(2 tables) and target db(11 tables). The problem is that field `customTableId` from source db is not a primary key. And when I set the value of it to `null` in source db I don't capture changes in target db. I don't have problems capturing changes from other columns like `customTableHref` or `customTableName`.

Comment: As analogue I can create view in Oracle ```CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "View_CustomTable" AS
SELECT "customTableId"   AS "id",
       "customTableHref" AS "href",
       "customTableName" AS "name",
       "customTableType" AS "type",
       "id"                    AS "quoteId"
FROM "MySourceTable"
WHERE "customTableId" IS NOT NULL;```

Comment: Also I should mention that If I edit customTableId I will get new insert in my target db.

Comment: After some thinking I figure out that I have to extract topic's tree "BEFORE
AFTER
SOURCE
■
OP
■
TS_MS
TRANSACTION" and change the data inside before and after. How can I do that with ksqldb ?